How to speed up redis-python pipeline?
I'm new to redis-py and need a fast queue and cache. I followed some tutorials and used redis pipelining to reduce server response times, but the following code still takes ~1ms to execute. After timing each step, it's clear that the bottleneck is waiting for pipe.execute() to run. How can I speed up the pipeline (aiming for at least 50,000 TPS or ~0.2ms per response), or is this runtime expected? This method running on a flask server, if that affects anything.
I'm also running redis locally with a benchmark get/set around 85,000 ops/second.
Here is my code:
redis_client = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0, decode_responses=True)

@app.route('/add_order_limit', methods=['POST'])
def add_order():
    starttime = time.time()
    data = request.get_json()
    ticker = data['ticker']
    user_id = data['user_id']
    quantity = data['quantity']
    limit_price = data['limit_price']
    created_at = time.time()
    order_type = data['order_type']
    
    order_obj = {
            "ticker": ticker,
            "user_id": user_id,
            "quantity": quantity,
            "limit_price": limit_price,
            "created_at": created_at,
            "order_type": order_type
        }
    
    pipe = redis_client.pipeline()
    
    order_hash = xxhash.xxh64_hexdigest(json.dumps(order_obj))
    
    
    # add object to redis hashes
    pipe.hset(
        order_hash, 
        mapping={
            "ticker": ticker,
            "user_id": user_id,
            "quantity": quantity,
            "limit_price": limit_price,
            "created_at": created_at,
            "order_type": order_type
        }
    )
    
    order_obj2 = order_obj
    order_obj2['hash'] = order_hash
    
    # add hash to user's set 
    pipe.sadd(f"user_{user_id}_open_orders", order_hash)
    
    
    limit_price_int = float(limit_price)
    limit_price_int = round(limit_price_int, 2)
    
    # add hash to priority queue
    pipe.zadd(f"{ticker}_{order_type}s", {order_hash: limit_price_int})
    

    pipe.execute()

    print(f"------RUNTIME: {time.time() - starttime}------\n\n")
    
    return json.dumps({
        "transaction_hash": order_hash,
        "created_at": created_at,
    })

Basically, I'm creating a Redis Hashes object for an 'order' object and pushing that to a sorted set doubling as a priority queue. I'm also keeping track of the active hashes for a user using a normal set. After running the above code, my server response time is around ~1ms on average, with variability as high as ~7ms. I also tried turning off decode_responses for the server settings but it doesn't reduce time. I don't think python concurrency would help either since there's not much calculating going on and the bottleneck is primarily the execution of the pipeline.
